# Cmder - How you can start in a specific directory

Tags: total-commander, cmder

How can I execute cmder with a specific current folder from total-commander?

Answer (score 1):

`cmder-1.3.2` can be started in specific folder with:

```
cmder /single <folder>
```

Since total-commander already configures the `Start in` folder for bat files with the folder from the tab, you can create a CMDER_ROOT/bin/**wsh.bat** file with the content:

```
cmder /single %CD%
```

Now, you can start a cmder shell from total-commander via `wsh`. This will add a new tab if cmder is already started. If you want to always start a new instance use /start instead of /single in your script.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this was your original intention, but another solution is to create an icon on the icons bar and use as `Parameters`:

```
/single "%p"
```

or

```
/start "%p"
```

This way you click on the icon and it starts in the TotalCommander specified directory.